# Ubuntu 14.10 desktop issue launcher and theme issue

Tags: launcher

I have typed `startx` command as a root after that I was unable to log on to my user account and for fixing this I have used command

```
sudo chown user:user $HOME
```

in terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

After that, I am able to log on. But, the problem is my desktop look has completely changed to Ubuntu 10.04 where there is no side bar (a launcher which has shortcuts and search button) which is called unity launcher. Now I am getting top and bottom task bars which is same as in ubuntu 10.04.

I want my Ubuntu 14.10 desktop look back: what I need to do for that (without any re-installation of OS)? Note: My guest account is not affected and I am seeing Ubuntu 14.10 look in that.

Comment: Is `user` your real username? If there is this folder `/home/user/`?

Answer (score 0):

you can reset unity and compiz by the following commands in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

and then

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

After that, run the below command to restart Unity

```
setsid unity
```

and then to reset the icons use the following code

```
unity --reset-icons
```

Comment: In my opinion it is still in the wrong permissions.

Comment: may be he has changed the ownership of the home folder.